# Como criar listas/arrays maiores do que 2GB (indexes usando uint/ulong) no C#?

Tags: c#, array, .net, asp.net, lista

Um dos problemas que tenho é de criar arrays no C#, e existem várias opções. Uma delas é usando o `List<T>` e o `Span<T>`, que me parecem mais conveniente.

Mas, um dos problemas é que todos eles apenas suportam `int` como index. Isso é, ao fazer `array[i]`, este `i` deve ser `int`:

```
var array = new List<byte>();
// ...
var dado = array[4294967295];
```

O código acima não funciona, uma vez que o `4294967295` excede o `int`. Isso faz com que seja impossível acessar valores superiores à 2^31. Consequentemente, isso faz com que a lista fique limitado há ~2GB, o que é um limite inferior até ao limite de sistemas de 32bits (que é cerca de ~4GB).

---

Indo mais afundo eu descobri que existe uma limitação geral, que impede objetos gerenciados de usarem mais de 2GB no C#, tanto no 32bits e 64bits. *Não encontrei informações sobre alocações na area não-gerenciada, e se tal limitação ainda existe lá.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tamanho maior que 2GB pode ser obtido desde o .NET 4.5 (ligando `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`).

Mas deseja mais de bilhões de elementos para ser acessado no índice, independente do tamanho. Isso não é possível já que o índice é um `int`, que vai até pouco mais de 2 bilhões (2^31).

A única solução possível é criar uma estrutura de dados que faça o armazenamento  dos dados em segmentos com *arrays* padrões, gerenciando isso como se fosse uma coisa só, e claro, o índice precisa ser `long`. Pode pegar os [fontes de `List`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) e mexer, mas dará trabalho porque a lista não tem vários segmentos para administrar, não é uma mudança tão simples.

[Alguém já tentou](https://gist.github.com/mjs3339/da6e42eaa88419a6ae9d6d58a3d02356), não sei se é bom.